# Line is not being drawn correctly on canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I am a newbie in HTML5 but have good experience of HTML. I was learning about canvas and thought of making a program. In this I was handling the user's mousedown and mouseup and was setting up the values of my variables according to the coordinates of the mouse. Then with the help of those I was stroking the line on the canvas which is not being drawn properly.

The work I have done to achieve this:

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bhaiya.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas"  style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
</canvas>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $x1 = 0;
    var $x2 = 0;
    var $y1 = 0;
    var $y2 = 0;

    $(this).mousedown(function(e){
        $x1 = e.pageX;
        $y1 = e.pageY;
    });

    $(this).mouseup(function(e){
        $x2 = e.pageX;
        $y2 = e.pageY;

        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var context = c.getContext("2d");
        context.moveTo($x1, $y1);
        context.lineTo($x2, $y2);
        context.stroke();
    });
});
```

**What is the problem? Any help would be appreciated! :)**

Comment: `context.moveTo(0, 0);` to `context.moveTo($x1, $y1);`, `context.lineTo(200, 200);` to `context.lineTo($x2, $y2);`, [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roine/j4XY8/1/)

Comment: What's the problem bothering you ? *"not being drawn properly"* isn't precise enough.

Comment: actually, the line is not drawn according to the mouse coordinates!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If you're bothered by the fact the drawing is fuzzy and doesn't seem to follow the x and y you give, then you can fix it like this :

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
c.width = c.clientWidth;
c.height = c.clientHeight;
```

2) you must take into account the offset due to the canvas position when it's not exactly in the top-left corner of the document :

```
$x1 = e.pageX-c.offsetLeft;
$y1 = e.pageY-c.offsetTop;
```

**[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/upuhur/1/edit)**

Note that in a real application you shouldn't recreate the context each time. In this case, you would also begin a new path when needed (probably at each click).

Comment: @AreebSiddiqui Did you try the demonstration ? Doesn't it work as you'd like ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.beginPath()`:

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(100, 150);
      context.lineTo(450, 50);
      context.stroke();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j4XY8/
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-canvas-painting/ (might be helpful)

Comment: not working, it jsut draw a line once(which is also not drawn according to the coordinates and draws no other line! :( any other help please.